# Parts of touchscreen not working and progressively getting worse - what's causing it?

Tags: touchscreen

First it was like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsiJll.png), then [this](https://m.imgur.com/a/Bdf1DSa), and now [this](https://imgur.com/UBVCje0). The white part is the part that's not responding to touch. Notice how it increases by an entire row in each picture. This is over a span of 3 weeks.

It's driving me crazy! What's causing it? I didn't drop the phone or get any water in it (as far as I can remember). It just happened suddenly. Does the digitizer go bad by itself without any physical damage? And why is it increasing like this?

It's the same in safe-mode and recovery. How do I diagnose this? I already ady cleaned the connector. I really don't want to get a new digitizer and then it turns out to be not it.

Thanks for any help!

Moto C Plus | Android 7 | Rooted

Comment: As already pointed out this is most likely a hardware damage. I am sorry but if you really want to know why your touch screen does not work correctly you should better ask some electronic experts. The screen as an electronic component is unrelated to Android.

Comment: Any idea where online would be the best place to ask?

Comment: You don't have to drop the phone or get it went to cause hardware defects. Electronic chips have internally components that degrade just by using it. Additionally humans are from a perspective of an electronic components really "hazardous entities". They emit sweat, dust, fat, use creams, and other chemicals and a lot of other things that can corrode or harm electronics.

Comment: You may try it on https://electronics.stackexchange.com (not sure if it really fits there) or may be on reddit.